# PHP Redirect Within website

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, refresh

I've been trying this code since 3 days in a row until a certain time (minutes or seconds) but unable to solve the problem.

My target is to redirect visitor to 10 random URLs which are being selected from a text file. The user will see a certain page for a certain time and then redirect to another page again, the number of pages he will be redirected to is complete RANDOM.

PROBLEM:

The problem is the visitor is not being redirected to any other page which is randomly selected from a text file, instead it is just refreshing the page... But I want to redirect him to other pages from the text file.. Hope you guys understood me by now.

EDIT: Found the problem. Actually the $rand_link is having NULL as it's value.. { [0]=> NULL } Don't know why.... ANy solution? Checked the 'BBnormalLinks.txt' file for it's permissions and that file is having some links in it for sure because I just checked it..

Thanks,

Here is the CODE:

```
<?php // Generate Random Nubmers.. 2 ********
            $numbers2 = range(13,70);

            shuffle($numbers2);

            for ($j=0;$j<1;$j++)
            {
            $numbers2[$j];
            }
                $seconds = numbers2[0];

            //////// For Random URL of Site
            $links = file('BBnormalLinks.txt');
        $rand_link = $links[ mt_rand(0, count($links) - 1) ];                   

                header("refresh:". $seconds .";url=". $rand_link); ?>
```

Comment: What's the point in this merry-go-round?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the value of $rand_link before doing anything with it?  On another note, why are you including those lines about $numbers2 when it doesn't seem to have anything to do with your problem?

Comment: Can you show us the keys and values of the array `$links`?

Comment: @Shrapnel: lol! :P I'm trying to build something using that......

Comment: @Farray: I put that 2 to test it. Anyways I'm now editing it and replace 2 with "$numbers2[0]"
And it's actually a random number generator. Hope you got me.

Comment: @scessor: the values of $links is extracted from the "BBnormalLinks.txt" file. and then in the next step "$rand_link" gets a random URL (Only 1 URL) from that text file.

Comment: @baburao113: I know what you want to do. I fear that the array `$links` is not filled as you suspect it. Can you show us the keys and values of this array? (E.g. with a `var_dump($links);`)

Comment: What does `$rand_link = $links[ mt_rand(0, count($links) - 1) ];` get? Do a `var_dump($rand_link)` to see that

Comment: @Starx ok doing that right now. thx will report back

Comment: @Starx You hit the nail dude! You are right,,, It's returning NULL value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is correct but some pointers that can cause this are

1. Some text have been outputted before the header is passed.
2. The random page, is not being generated, thus ending up refreshing the same page again and again.

I have a very strong feeling, that your `$rand_link` is returning blank or null.

---

#### Update:

After a few discussion, the problem was the evil `path` again.

```
$links = file('patotofile\BBnormalLinks.txt');
```

As baburao113, quoted

> I had to move that file to wordpress theme folder lol! Problem resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

From the little I know about the refresh header, it does not seem to be the most reliable thing to count on. (I'd guess not all browsers respond to it.) Since you are showing content, at least for a few seconds, you could try using [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) in a [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) in JavaScript instead. So something like:

```
$content = '<script type="text/javascript">window.setTimeout("window.location=\''.$rand_link.'\';", '.($seconds*1000).');</script>';
```

Comment: Thanks dude... After searching for a method with solely php and coming to conclusion that it is not possible, your solution was my last resort.

Comment: Glad I could help. Are you saying you gave up on the refresh header?

Comment: yes I gave up on refresh header.. And I don't know why when I use your code for testing in an empty file it works, and when I use it in my full code, then it won't work unless I change PHP variables in your script like $rand_link to http://google.com and $seconds to 5.

There is another countdown timer in my full code.. One is in the above code which you have shared here. And another one is in the full code. And I can't share that full code here.

Comment: It sounds like the variables are not set when you build the "content." Have a look at the source and look for the `setTimeout` line to see that the variables have passed something legit to the content. You can have as many timeouts as you want. There COULD be some javascript killing ALL timeouts, but I'd doubt that (but go ahead and check for it).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the contents of 'BBnormalLinks.txt' or the final value of $rand_link, it is difficult to say precisely what is going wrong.

Your usage of `file()` and `mt_rand()` appear to be correct, though you aren't doing anything to ensure that you are getting a valid URL.

This is purely conjecture, but I suspect that you don't have PHP properly configured to display errors.  If the file fails to load, $links will have a null value going into your penultimate line.  You will then try to access element 0 of a null array and receive an empty value.  This will result in `header('refresh:2;url=')` and your page will simply refresh itself every 2 seconds.

Comment: the 'BBnormalLinks.txt' is perfectly fine, I can assure that. It only have 10 URLs. Which I myself wrote them down. And when I echo "$rand_link" it's printing the url on the page. So This is the reason I'm pulling my hair right now.

Comment: @baburao113 Since you have been working on this problem for 3 days, you shouldn't be assured that any part of your code is fine.  Regardless, read my answer again.  My suggestion is that you are not loading the file properly.  One way to debug this would be to comment out your header line and put `echo $rand_link` just to verify that the URL is loading correctly from your file.

Comment: I'm speechless dude.. I said I already did that...... Please read my last comment :\

Comment: @baburao113 To be honest, I didn't pay a ton of attention to the rest of your comment after you assured me that your file was well and good.  If you've already taken steps to debug your problem, you should detail the steps and results in your question.  There are many people who would help you, but you are making it difficult.

Comment: ok dude... I just did "var_dump($rand_link);" and found that all values are NULL NULL NULL NULL ... . ... ..

Comment: @baburao113 Still speechless?  =)

Comment: lol!! I don't know what's happening at all now.. It's all so messed up :P

Now that you successfully found the problem. Can you please help me with this? :D